# "He is a genius, he is." Is there a term for the "he is" addition to this sentence?

Tags: terminology

Just as we have tail-questions (or question tags), affirmative additions to affirmative remarks ("so do I", "so did he") and negative additions to negative remarks ("neither do I", "neither would I", etc), is there a term for this kind of addition to a sentence?

- "Despite all the corruption, he was re-elected. He is a masterpiece, **he is**."
- "She is a fly customer, **she is**."
- "He is a genius, **he is**.

Comment: Dislocation:http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dislocation_(syntax)

Comment: @Josh61 Good link.

Comment: Seems like this construction is far less common in American English.  Reading this, even in my head it comes across with an English accent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called right dislocation, and it's covered in *CGEL* Ch.16, §8.2 (pp. 1411-1412) where the dislocated constituent is said to be subject to two constraints:

- It must be *discourse-old*—the entity referred to must have been previously introduced into the discourse.
- It must be *topical*—the entity referred to must be the topic of the immediately preceding discourse.

Comment: Is there a CGEL online?

Comment: Unluckily not!!!!

Comment: In Northern Ireland it is *so he is*. *I went to London, so I did*.

Comment: @WS2 Not just Northern—that’s used in all of Ireland (and sometimes Scotland, too?).

Comment: Note that this is Huddleston & Pullum's 2002 *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, not Quirk et al's 1985 *Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language*.  Unfortunately, they share the acronym CGEL.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I am sure you are right about 'all of Ireland'. But I spent a two-week holiday in the Republic last summer and I do not recall hearing it once. I do however remember it very much from forty-five years ago when I had Northern Ireland flatmates in London. I don't associate it with Scotland at all.

Comment: I disagree. [Right dislocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dislocation_(syntax)) takes the form "He is a genius, John is." Here "John" is dislocated from the main clause. In "He is a genius, he is", nothing is missing from the main clause; it is a [tag statement](https://glossary.sil.org/term/tag-statement).