# Word-order in sentence of The Silence of the Lambs

Tags: word-order, syntactic-analysis

A sentence in the Chapter 11 of [*The Silence of the Lambs*](https://books.google.com/books?id=1d3XWXXxnEsC&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22The+Silence+of+the+Lambs%22+Harris&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwihiL7lo8rRAhXjilQKHd0GDS8Q6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=%22had%20Bill%22&f=false) by Thomas Harris has a strange grammatical structure for me.

It sounds like out of order, even though I can't think exactly what would be a good order.

The sentence is:

> He had done it five times that they knew of, had Bill.

I understand the meaning, but can't grasp why the author choose this way to deliver it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["He is a genius, he is." Is there a term for the "he is" addition to this sentence?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/226010/he-is-a-genius-he-is-is-there-a-term-for-the-he-is-addition-to-this-senten)

Comment: It's a similar question, certainly—but the "he is ..., he is" construction can only serve the purpose of emphasis, since it exactly repeats the earlier two words, whereas "He had ..., had Bill" can very reasonably be treated as a clarification construction. Ultimately, I think, the two questions involve at least somewhat different subjects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see it as a colloquial form used to informally clarify a potentially ambiguous reference. Out of context, it's impossible to say whether the clarification was actually needed in this instance, but

> He had done it five times that they knew of, had Bill.

expresses in an informal, spoken-English way the same idea you might convey in writing with

> He (Bill) had done it five times that they knew of.

In some instances, however, the point of the form may be not to resolve a possible ambiguity (as with "he had, had Bill") but to emphasize the person and act mentioned earlier in the sentence, and perhaps to provide metrical bounce. In that respect, it calls to mind sing-song verses of this type:

> James James/ Morrison Morrison/ Wetherby George Dupree/ Took great/ Care of his Mother,/ Though he was only three./ James James/ Said to his Mother,/ 'Mother,' **he said, said he**;/ 'You must never go down to the end of the town if you don't go down with me.'

The preceding is from a poem titled "[Disobedience](https://books.google.com/books?id=rjLTsncFKCgC&pg=PA223&dq=%22said+said+he%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJw4acpcrRAhUW1GMKHcEKCsI4HhDoAQgbMAA#v=onepage&q=%22said%20said%20he%22&f=false)," written by A. A. Milne in 1924. But you can find the same reverse repetition of actor and action in Walter Scott, [*Old Mortality*](https://books.google.com/books?id=AAgOAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA237&dq=%22he+said+said+he%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiExenxncrRAhVqjFQKHR8DC3E4ChDoAQg1MAU#v=onepage&q=%22he%20said%20said%20he%22&f=false) (1816):

> He had been gi'eing me preceeze directions anent the bread and the wine, and the brandy, at his burial, and how often it was to be handed round the company, (for, dead or alive, he was a prudent, frugal, pains-taking man) and then **he said, said he,** 'Ailie,' (he aye ca'd me Ailie, we were auld acquaintance) 'Ailie, take ye care and haud the gear weel thegither; for the name of Morton of Milnwood's ga'en out like the last sough of an auld sang.'

This manner of providing clarification or emphasis probably began as a colloquial way of speaking; I imagine that it persists in the speech of some English-speaking areas far more prominently than in others. In written English, it survives (barely) as a way to convey a similarly unrefined presentation of information, either to further the general tone of the narrative or for ironic effect.