# What does “was Troy” mean in this sentence?

Tags: phrase-usage

I recently read this sentence:

> He was doing a good job, was Troy.

What do the words "was Troy" mean at the end of the sentence?

Comment: Related: [“He is a genius, he is.” Is there a term for the “he is” addition to this sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/226010)

Comment: @sumelic - That's not a related question.  It would only be a related question if the phrase were "Troy was" instead of "was Troy."  Saying "was Troy" clearly means that the period should be a question mark and that "Troy" is someone other than the subject "he."

Comment: @amarbhatti: Please [edit] your question to add a mention of the source of this sentence. This way potential answerers have the option to research its context, which can improve their answer's quality. (e.g. by ruling out answers based on incorrect assumptions.) ... I searched around a bit and was able to find it used in *The Outsider* by Stephen King. Is this where you found this sentence as well?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["He is a genius, he is." Is there a term for the "he is" addition to this sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/226010/he-is-a-genius-he-is-is-there-a-term-for-the-he-is-addition-to-this-senten)

Answer (score 3):

**This is repetition in reverse order to emphasize a thought**.

Consider: **Troy was** doing a good job, **was Troy**.

This is a **poetic device called antimetabole**, where you reverse the order of words as in the witches in MacBeth who say: **Fair is foul and foul is fair.**

**Troy was** is the subject and verb (part of the verb) in the first clause, and "was Troy" predicate in the second one. Now, in this case, it is not a real antimetabole because we have "he" and "Troy".

However, if one admits that "Troy" and "he" are actually synonyms in the sentence, then it is one.

There are uses like this found in regional dialects though I cannot prove that. And probably mostly in the English in Scotland, England and Ireland.

Sentences like: **John was a good man, was John** are common in speech by characters in novels etc.

It can also be termed **antistrophe**, which is a repetition of words in reverse order.

[detailed explanation of antimetabole](https://study.com/academy/lesson/antimetabole-definition-examples.html)

Comment: In the OP’s example “He was doing a good job, was Troy”, where is the repetition in reverse order? Another example: “he is a big man, he is” there is similarly no repetition in reverse order. Antimetabole would be something like “peace is love, and love is peace”.

Comment: **He was** doing a good job, **was he**. **He was** is one order, **was he (Troy)** is the reverse of it. You might want to reread my answer. Fair is foul and foul is fair = peace is love and love is peace. That shows me you did not really read my answer.  Perhaps, it's an antistrophe would be better for mine.

Comment: "He was" is not "was Troy" in reverse. You are literally changing the example to make it fit your theory.  How about "he is a big man, he is"? Where is the reversed word order? What about  "they went to the shop, they did" - where is the reversed order? This is *not* antimetabole. It is a right dislocation construction.  Learn about that here -> https://kb.osu.edu/bitstream/handle/1811/84885/1/Toma_Honors_Thesis.pdf and here -> https://orca-mwe.cf.ac.uk/38674/1/EWW-Postprint%20MDurham.pdf.

Answer (score 2):

If there was a question mark it could definitely be a question. The "was Troy" part would make the question explicit after the statement of the topic in question that comes before the comma. In other words, "In terms of the the topic of doing a good job, did Troy fit that assessment?"

But, in fact, as written, the sentence is not a question but rather would be a fine answer to a question.

For example:

Q: I know Troy was working for you before he abruptly left town. When it came to the job, how was Troy (doing)?

A: He was doing a good job, was Troy.

The "was Troy" would be a mirror to the form of the original question. The "was Troy" is not strictly necessary but does add reinforcement to the positive assessment.

"He" is a reference to Troy and whether it's written "was Troy" or "Troy was" the meaning is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

> He was doing a good job,was Troy.

It means:

> Troy was doing a good job.

but it is arranged so that "Troy" is only mentioned at the end.  Why would you do that?  Perhaps for stylistic reasons.  And perhaps this construction is common in certain dialects of English.

If you speak English and you never use this construction, you will be fine.  But you should be able to understand when someone else uses it.