# "She was beautiful, she was."

Tags: speech, repetition

What is the term used to describe sentences such as:

> They did all they could, they did.
> It was a gorgeous day, it was.

EDIT: Thank you so much to all who helped; you guys are great!

Comment: The form of words where a statement is made then repeated immediately is a common form of emphasis in many dialects of spoken English, it's certainly very common in British vernacular speech, but it's rarely if ever used in written English. As I said it is used for emphasis "That was a job and a half, that was" means that the task was very hard "It was a gorgeous day, it was" means that the weather was exceptionally good, "She's a pretty girl , she is" means that she is _really_ pretty and so on. There is almost certainly a word for the form but I don't know it. Someone else probably does.

Comment: The technical term for the rule is Right Dislocation. The subject noun phrase is moved to the end of the sentence, and a pronoun is left behind. There is also Left Dislocation (though not with this sentence, which already has a pronoun subject). _My old may, he can fix anything_ (left) vs _He can fix anything, my old man_ (right). These are copying rules, not movement rules that don't leave a pronoun, like Topicalization: _This one I like; the others i don't like._

Comment: @Araucaria It looks like a 'tag statement'; the parallel one associated with Irish English includes 'so'. 'He had a pony, so he did.' 'It's Pat and Mick, so it is.'

Comment: @JohnLawler 
Is it a RD though? It has an aux attached. Is it perhaps a tag of some sort?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks for that comment. I've redone mine because I forgot to ping John Lawler on it.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. No, you're right, It's a tag statement, not RD. My mistake. RD would be _She was beautiful, that woman_.

Comment: Can someone make an answer out of these comments?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["He is a genius, he is." Is there a term for the "he is" addition to this sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/226010/he-is-a-genius-he-is-is-there-a-term-for-the-he-is-addition-to-this-senten)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Yes, the question is a duplicate; but unfortunately the only answer there makes the same mistake as John Lawler did before he saw the light -- it calls it Right Dislocation.

Comment: @TonyK Yes; I've transferred my close-vote to that question (though not that OP's fault) and added a correct answer here.

Answer (score 2):

Just as

- *They did all they could, didn't they?*

has a tag question (/question tag) appended,

- *They did all they could, they did.*

has a **tag statement** (a restatement, perhaps for emphasis but a common style device in say Irish English) appended.

> *Tag Statement*:
>
> A tag statement is an elliptical statement that follows and echoes a
> main clause statement.
>
> Examples:  In English, a subject noun or pronoun followed or preceded
> by an auxiliary verb as in the following example is a tag statement:
>
> - *He made a good showing, did Bill.*

[[SIL: Glossary of Linguistic Terms](https://glossary.sil.org/term/tag-statement)]