# "This is a good one, this is"

Tags: british-english, vernacular

I have long been curious about a particular English (in parts of GB) phrasing habit.

For example:

> Oh she's lovely, *she is*.
> That's a nice one, *that is*.
> You should keep doing that, *you should*.

I am curious what that repeat is called, how it came about, and anything else I can find out.

Comment: I hear this in the US occasionally, though it may be more common in the UK.

Comment: It's simple assertion, similar to talking with someone: A: "Oh she's lovely." B: "*She is*."

Comment: Sort of rhetoric  assertion. Similar to the more common rhetoric question: - she is lovely, is she?

Comment: @WeatherVane It's a tag.

Comment: As My Fair Lady made the line famous with "I'm a good girl, I am," Liza Doolittle spoke in a Cockney style and was adding emphasis.

Comment: My favorite still, heard at the snooker tournament was, "He plans his approach carefully, does Ronnie O'Sullivan."

Comment: @Elliot: That's a different structure, though – your example features subject-verb inversion, while the tags in the question all use canonical word order.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["He is a genius, he is." Is there a term for the "he is" addition to this sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/226010/he-is-a-genius-he-is-is-there-a-term-for-the-he-is-addition-to-this-senten) See also [She was beautiful, she was](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/564751/she-was-beautiful-she-was/573292#573292).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Deleted, alas.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cambridge Dictionaries calls these **statement tags** in an article (["Tags"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/tags), *English Grammar Today*, Cambridge Dictionary, accessed 25 July 2023)

It says:

> We can use a statement tag to emphasise or reinforce an affirmative statement. The tag is also affirmative. They typically invite the listener to agree or sympathise in some way, or to offer a parallel comment. Statement tags are very informal

Examples they give include

> I’m bored with this, I am.

> She won some money last week, Catherine did.

As you can see, the simplest form is if you have pronoun plus auxiliary form of "to be" when you just repeat the pronoun and the uncontracted form of "to be": "I'm bored" to "I am".

You can use "do" or "did" in place of a verb in the present or past tense. ("I play golf all the time, I do.") And you have the option of using a person's name or other noun. ("They like it when you buy them things, girls do.") (Examples in this paragraph are my own.)

Generally they are used in casual speech, inviting agreement or providing a bit of emphasis.

Answer (score 4):

Some linguists call this "expanded right dislocation (ERD)", though the use of "right dislocation" to refer to clauses with a verb is not without controversy. There are several other names in use as well:

> These three types of right dislocation ["noun", "noun verb", "verb noun"] tend to be grouped under one term, making it more difficult to fully establish what their distribution may be in various studies. Durham (2007) and Timmis (2009), however, separate them and this is done in the present analysis as well. Because this paper considers the feature as right dislocation, it will follow the taxonomy used in Durham (2007), whereby the variants were categorized as standard right dislocation (SRD), as in (12), expanded right dislocation (ERD), as in (13), and reverse right dislocation (RRD), as in (14), respectively. Timmis (2009: 332), who uses the term tails throughout, classifies these three variants as noun phrase tails, simple operator tails and inverted operator tails.
>
> - (12) I was a little angel me (025)
> - (13) He stayed with this other woman John did (003)
> - (14) She got a great bargain did her Mum (034)
>
> [...]
>
> Right dislocation is referred to by a multitude of other names, both in dialectological and syntactic literature. Quirk et al. (1985) use the term *amplificatory tags*, Petyt (1985) examines *emphatic tags*, Melchers (1983) deals with *tag statements*, Wright (1909) and Visser (1963) classify it as *subject repetition*. Finally, in the field of literature on focus, they are sometimes called *tails* (see Aijmer 1989; Timmis 2009).

From [Right dislocation in Northern England: frequency and use — perception meets reality](https://orca.cardiff.ac.uk/id/eprint/38674/1/EWW-Postprint%20MDurham.pdf) by Mercedes Durham

Comment: Nice answer, this.

Comment: Surely "right" dislocation as a term must irritate those who speak languages with right-to-left writing systems.

Comment: I wish I could have equally accepted both answers! Thank you Laurel and Stuart!